# touchcarousel not working when template loaded with ajax in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

**index.php**

```
<div id="carousel-image-and-text" class="touchcarousel grey-blue sbSlider">       
      <ul class="touchcarousel-container  item-list"  <?php echo "id='".$catId."'"; ?> > 
      </ul> 
</div>
```

**js:**

```
 $(document).live( "pagebeforecreate", function( e, data ) { 
                    $( ".item-list" ).each(function( index ) { 
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");  
                       $.ajax({ 
                            url: "/test.html",
                            context: document.body
                             }).done(function(html) {  
                               // $("#"+id).append(html); 
                              $("#"+id).replaceWith(html);
                        });  
                       // alert(id); 
                     }); 

      });
```

**test.html**

```
 <li class="touchcarousel-item"><a href="gift-page.html"><span><img src="/images/spacer.gif" style="background:url(https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/p128x128/851586_168401033316275_1834897920_n.png) no-repeat center center; background-size:auto 50px"/></span><strong>Napoli</strong><font>Food and Drinks</font><label><i></i>15</label></a></li>
   <li class="touchcarousel-item"><a href="gift-page.html"><span><img src="/images/spacer.gif" style="background:url(https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p128x128/851586_641022952579983_1053547819_n.png) no-repeat center center; background-size:auto 50px"/></span><strong>Pusheen</strong><font>Food and Drinks</font><label>FREE</label></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong, but it seems like you are replacing your `<UL>` with and `<LI>`. 
So this means you will only have `<LI>` with out an `<UL>`. In this case i think you should use `.append` instead of `.replaceWith`

Comment: but .append also not working as you can see i have commented ..this line

Comment: But when you append does it add the <li> in your <UL> ?

Comment: yes both both code added <li> but problem is img background not showing as you seen in https url and touchcarousel not working (only when I use ajax without ajax its working fine)

Comment: Well then i believe its an ansync problem,  when do you call the touch plugin. Be sure to  run the above code, before the touch plugin. Ans try placing the above in a document.ready.